# Google Maps MapView displays grid, not map

Tags: android, google-maps

I have been messing with this error for several days. When I run my app, I get the MapView to open but the map doesn't display. It only shows a grid that you can move around and zoom in and out.

I have generated two new API keys thinking that it was that, but it still doesn't work. And yes, I do have the internet permission under the manifest file.

Comment: Is there anything interesting in logcat?

Comment: Are you using the debug key API key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you definitely using an API key generated from your debug keystore and specifying appropriately in your layout?
If you generate the API key from your own private key then it will not work when you send debug versions to your device, because they are signed with the debug key.

[The guide to getting the MD5 of your Debug Certificate.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey#getdebugfingerprint)

Comment: That was it! Thank you! I was using the jdk keytool and signing my application. It was a mess! Thank you so much!